issue in Rpi4-8gb When I try change bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb in Debian-12 64 bits
neuberfran@raspberrypi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
neuberfran@raspberrypi:~$ arch
aarch64
neuberfran@raspberrypi:~$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux
neuberfran@raspberrypi:~$ uname -m
aarch64

U-Boot> printenv bootcmd
bootcmd=fatload mmc 0 ${kernel_addr_r} kernel8.img;fatload mmc 0 ${fdt_addr} ${fdtfile}; booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}

I have rpi4 with debian 12 (as above) and I'm trying to change bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb, starting with the commands below:
mkdir rasp_arm64
cd rasp_arm64/
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm
sudo apt-get install lzop
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
cd linux/
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- mrproper
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- bcm2711_defconfig
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules dtbs
make -j8 ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- dtbs
ls -lha arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neuuberfran neuuberfran 55K Jul 12 13:02 arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb

config.txt (file) 
enable_uart=1
kernel=u-boot.bin
arm_64bit=1

git branch 
  master
* my6.6.20

Issue I'm having, right in U-boot, described below:
2024.04-rc4-0004

0-gbd0aedde3e-dirty (Mar 23 2024 - 10:37:01 -0300)

DRAM: 948 MiB (effective 7.9 GiB)
RPI 4 Model B (0xd03115)
Core: 210 devices, 15 uclasses, devicetree: board
MMC:  mmcnr@7e300000: 1, mmc@7e340000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... OK
In:  serial,usbkbd
Out:  serial,vidconsole
Err:  serial,vidconsole
Net:  eth0: ethernet@7d580000
starting USB...
No working controllers found
Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0 
9259827 bytes read in 413 ms (21.4 MiB/s)
Failed to load 'broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb'
  Uncompressing Kernel Image to 0
Moving Image from 0x80000 to 0x200000, end=1b60000
ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
Could not find a valid device tree

Note.: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=314845
Similar issue, but in CM4 module
Can anyone help-me?

So apparently you have kernel source on some unspecified development host and an RPi. You build a kernel Image and .dtb (on the unspecified development host), and then try to boot the RPi from an SD card. Duh! What files did you copy to the SD card??? What's on the SD card when you try to boot??? That's the salient information that you neglect to provide! Sanity check: is your newly built kernel Image exactly 9259827 bytes?

@sawdust There is only one image on the SD card=Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) that I took from this official website=https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/
I just removed the rpi4 sdcard, I insert in my PC and delete the bcm2711-rpi-b.dtb that came with it and insert the new DTB (which I compiled as above) which is almost the same size. I put the sdcard back on the rpi4 and get the error.
The sanity of the sdcard seems OK. As I said above in the topic, it works normally with the original DTB.

One more time: What's on the SD card? Not your condensed description, but a full directory listing. Odds are that you're missing the broadcom subdirectory.

@sawdust Tks. You can download it here: https://github.com/neuberfran/stackoverflow2

"I just ... delete the bcm2711-rpi-b.dtb that came with it and insert the new DTB" - So on which filesystem did you perform these operations? Why are you showing us the contents of the ext4 filesystem? According to the U-Boot bootcmd variable you posted, the dtb file is read from a FAT filesystem. Maybe I wasn't explicit, but isn't the first partition of the SD card containing a FAT fs the filesystem of interest when booting??? The error message you're getting isn't a complicated issue. That error is due to carelessness.

@sawdust Always making it clear that the correct one is bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb. The error is really clear=Could not find a valid device tree. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2236483#p2236483  I don't see any other solution other than for someone to try these steps on the rpi4 (maybe on the rpi5) and see if the error appears.

Seems like you're only reading the last line of the U-Boot log. Instead you need to focus on the first failure message (before the failure propagates), which is Failed to load 'broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb'. This is a clear and simple indication of what you did wrong. There is no need "for someone to try these steps" because the solution is simply to copy the .dtb file to the same place as you specified in the fdtfile environment variable. One more time: odds are that you're missing the broadcom subdirectory. If you did a U-Boot fatls command that could be obvious.

@sawdust https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=370802 Yes, I tried to change the DTB of /boot/firmware today and what I feared happened. I lost this sdcard. Even though I backed up and restored the firmware folder using sudo nautilus, etc.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bYKUuEpz2djagDTqwUvQzizOBR_kKvXH/view?usp=drive_link

@sawdust The same DTB file in /boot/firmware is on the boot partition (fat32) in sdcard. I mount in /mnt. I recovery my sdcard

@sawdust https://github.com/TImada/raspi4_freertos/blob/master/dts/raspi4-rpmsg.dtso This is what I want to include in the rpi4 main DTB. Via dtc I built the DTBO (overlay) I configured it correctly but I haven't had any success yet. I discovered that U-boot (I need it in this project) does not allow overlay. Do you know how to get around this? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=134018  https://github.com/TImada/raspi4_freertos

First of all, to resolve my issue I recreated an image (with SSH, Wifi, etc) for my rpi4 8gb, using Imager App (version 1.8.5) on Ubuntu 20.04:

https://hechao.li/2021/12/20/Boot-Raspberry-Pi-4-Using-uboot-and-Initramfs/

Then, based on the website above, I created U-boot 2024.04 and boot.scr (specifically) as below:

cat << EOF > boot_cmd.txt
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} Image
setenv bootargs "8250.nr_uarts=1 console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait rw"
booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}
EOF
~/u-boot/tools/mkimage -A arm64 -O linux -T script -C none -d boot_cmd.txt boot.scr

config.txt (I don`t need more cmdline.txt, I delete it)
1.enable_uart=1
2.arm_64bit=1
3.kernel=u-boot.bin
4.#dtoverlay=disable-bt

I put files: config.txt, bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb (already with the necessary changes for RPMsg), Image, boot.scr and u-boot.bin in bootfs partition.

I insert sdcard in rpi4 8gb and access it using sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0:



